# cancelling or killing a pthread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

```
gcc (GCC) 4.6.3
valgrind-3.6.1
```

I have created a application that send and receives some messages in 2 different thread for sending and receiving. Using pthreads, condition varables and mutexes for locks.

However, the sender will send messages and then signal the receiver to receive it and process it. It does this in a while loop.

However, the problem occurs if I want to quit the application by using ctrl-c and handling the interupt. If there is no messages being sent then the receiver is stuck in the while loop waiting to receive.

The main thread will call join and block waiting for the receiver to finish. But it doesn't as it waiting on the `pthread_cond_wait`.

I was thinking of using the `pthread_cancel` or `pthread_kill`. But I don't like to do that as it doesn't allow the thread to exit normally.

many thanks for any suggestions.

**main function**

```
    void main(void)
    {
        /* Do some stuff here */

    /* Start thread that will send a message */
    if(pthread_create(&thread_recv_id, &thread_attr, thread_recv_fd, NULL) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create thread, reason [ %s ]",
            strerror(errno));
            break;
        }
        printf("Start listening for receiving data'\n");

        /* Start thread to receive messages */
        if(pthread_create(&thread_send_id, &thread_attr, thread_send_fd, NULL) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create thread for receiving, reason [ %s ]",
                    strerror(errno));
            break;
        }

    /* Clean up threading properties */
    pthread_join(thread_send_id, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread_recv_id, NULL); <---- blocking here waiting for the recv thread to finish

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex_queue);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&cond_queue);

    return 0;
}
```

**sender thread**

```
void *thread_send_fd()
{
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_queue);
        if(send_fd((int)fd) == FALSE) {
            /* Just continue to send another item */
            continue;
        }
        /* Signal the waiting thread to remove the item that has been sent */
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond_queue);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_queue);
}
```

**receiver thread**

```
void *thread_recv_fd()
{
    while(is_receiving()) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_queue);

        /* Wait for an item to be sent on the queue */
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond_queue, &mutex_queue); <---- waiting here

        queue_remove();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_queue);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: If you do not join to the recv thread, it will not block the exit of your main thread and the OS will stop both.  If the recv thread holds no inter-process resources or the like, just let the OS stop it.

Answer (score 9):

You basically have 3 choices:

1. Use `pthread_cancel`. This will interrupt the `pthread_cond_wait` call, and then exit the thread, invoking the cancellation handlers registered with `pthread_cleanup_push` on the way up.
2. Use `pthread_kill` to **send a signal to the thread**. This doesn't "kill" the thread, it just sends a signal. In this case, you must have registered a signal handler in that thread for the signal you use, and that signal handler must do something to tell the thread to exit. This isn't particularly better than the third option, since the signal handler still needs to do something to make the `pthread_cond_wait` loop exit.
3. Add a manual interruption feature to your thread that knows to set a flag and signal the condition variable. The loop around `pthread_cond_wait` should then check the flag and exit the thread if the flag is set.

I would recommend (1) or (3). Using `pthread_cancel` is most generic, but requires careful handling in the thread to ensure there are suitable `pthread_cleanup_push` calls for cleaning up all resources allocated by the thread, unlocking all mutexes, and so forth. Writing a manual interruption feature is potentially more work, but can be most easily tailored to your application.

Comment: 4.  Stop using join when it it not necessary.